# Integrate with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I would like to integrate the function :

$$ int_0^R sqrt(R^2 - x^2) dx $$

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
R = symbols('R', real = True, constant = True)
integrate(sqrt(R**2-x**2),(x,0,R))
```

But it solves me this one in complex domain. Is-it possible to force sympy to give me the result which is PI R^2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare both x and R to be positive then you can get a simpler result but it's `pi R^2/4`:

```
In [4]: x, R = symbols('x, R', positive=True)                                                                                                                                                               

In [5]: Integral(sqrt(R**2-x**2),(x,0,R)).doit()                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: 
   2
π⋅R 
────
 4
```